# Streamlit and VSCode: What are the solutions to these challenges?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, visual-studio-code, streamlit

I'm trying to run a web app on streamlit using VScode, but I've been getting error messages of which some were solved from solutions given here in SO. The remaining errors still persist and I don't know what to do; this is my first web app. The data used for my model have about 18 features, although, only eight were selected in feature selection: I still imported all the features in the dataframe, but want my app to display only three buttons (facility name, state and year) because the user wouldn't have the information of the other five entries. The app displays on my web browser and everything works fine except the predict button. I appreciate your response, here's my code:

```
from joblib import load
import streamlit as st
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import queue

q = queue.Queue()

try:
    task = q.get(False)
except queue.Empty:
    # Handle empty queue here
    pass
else:
    # Handle task here and call q.task_done()
    q.task_done()

@st.cache
def read_csv(path):
    return pd.read_csv(path)

new_df = read_csv('C:/Users/user/Desktop/DataScience/new_data.csv')
df = new_df[['number_of_completed_surveys','hcahps_linear_mean_value','survey_response_rate_percent','hcahps_answer_percent',
'patient_survey_star_rating','facility_name','year','hospital_type','hospital_ownership','emergency_services',
'meets_criteria_for_promoting_interoperability_of_ehrs','state','mortality_national_comparison',                         
'safety_of_care_national_comparison','readmission_national_comparison','patient_experience_national_comparison',                         
'effectiveness_of_care_national_comparison','timeliness_of_care_national_comparison',                         
'efficient_use_of_medical_imaging_national_comparison','hospital_overall_rating']]                         

load_model = load('C:/Users/user/Desktop/DataScience/ushospital_model.joblib')

def welcome():
    return 'Welcome all'

def US_hospital_prediction(*args):
     """ 
     Predict the overall rating of Hospitals in the US.
     
     This function uses more parameters than listed below;
     but these are given as parameters to be used in the app.
     
     Parameters:
     -----------  
     name : facility_name
         In: query
         Type: str
         Required: true
     name : state
         In: query
         Type: str
         Required: true
     name : year
         In: query
         Type: str
         Required: true
     name : hospital_overall_rating
         Description: the output values
     """
     prediction = load_model.predict([['number_of_completed_surveys','hcahps_linear_mean_value','survey_response_rate_percent','hcahps_answer_percent',
     'patient_survey_star_rating','facility_name','year','hospital_type','hospital_ownership','emergency_services',
     'meets_criteria_for_promoting_interoperability_of_ehrs','state','mortality_national_comparison',                         
     'safety_of_care_national_comparison','readmission_national_comparison','patient_experience_national_comparison',                         
     'effectiveness_of_care_national_comparison','timeliness_of_care_national_comparison',                         
     'efficient_use_of_medical_imaging_national_comparison']])
     
     print(prediction)
     return prediction

def main():
    st.title('United States Hospital Rating Predictor')
    html_temp = """
    <div style="background-color:lime;padding:10px">
    <h2 style="color:maroon;text-align:center;">Want to know the best hospitals in the country? <h2>
    """
    st.markdown(html_temp, unsafe_allow_html=True)
    #Add sidebar to the app
    st.sidebar.markdown("### About")
    st.sidebar.markdown('This app rates hospitals from 1 to 5 and is built with Streamlit')
    #Create two columns
    col1, col2 = st.columns(2)
    with col1:
        hosp_name = df['facility_name'].unique().tolist()
        hosp_name.sort()
        facility = st.selectbox("Select Hospital", hosp_name)
    with col2:
        us_state=df['state'].unique().tolist()
        us_state.sort()
        state = st.selectbox("Select State", us_state, index=0)
    year = st.text_input('Year', 'Type Here')
    result = ""
    if st.button('Predict'):
        result = US_hospital_prediction(df.iloc[:,:-1])
    st.success('The Hospital rating is {}'.format(result))

     
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This is the error message:

```
 You can now view your Streamlit app in your browser.

  Local URL: http://localhost:8502
  Network URL: http://192.168.43.104:8502

2022-07-12 12:47:39.429 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\snowflakes\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py", line 822, in dispatch_one_batch
    tasks = self._ready_batches.get(block=False)        
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\snowflakes\lib\queue.py", line 167, in get
    raise Empty
_queue.Empty

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\snowflakes\lib\site-packages\streamlit\scriptrunner\script_runner.py", line 475, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\DataScience\US_hospital_rating_app.py", line 131, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\DataScience\US_hospital_rating_app.py", line 126, in main
    result = US_hospital_prediction(df.iloc[:,:-1])     
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\DataScience\US_hospital_rating_app.py", line 87, in US_hospital_prediction        
    prediction = load_model.predict([['number_of_completed_surveys','hcahps_linear_mean_value','survey_response_rate_percent','hcahps_answer_percent',
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\snowflakes\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\metaestimators.py", line 113, in <lambda>
    out = lambda *args, **kwargs: self.fn(obj, *args, **kwargs)  # noqa
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\snowflakes\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py", line 469, in predict    
    Xt = transform.transform(Xt)
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\snowflakes\lib\site-packages\sklearn\compose\_column_transformer.py", line 
748, in transform
    Xs = self._fit_transform(
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\snowflakes\lib\site-packages\sklearn\compose\_column_transformer.py", line 
606, in _fit_transform
    return Parallel(n_jobs=self.n_jobs)(
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\snowflakes\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py", line 1043, in __call__   
    if self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\snowflakes\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py", line 833, in dispatch_one_batch
    islice = list(itertools.islice(iterator, big_batch_size))
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\snowflakes\lib\site-packages\sklearn\compose\_column_transformer.py", line 
609, in <genexpr>
    X=_safe_indexing(X, column, axis=1),
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\snowflakes\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py", line 370, in _safe_indexing
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Specifying the columns using strings is only supported for pandas DataFrames
```

Comment: It doesn't really make sense (to me) that you are passing a big list of field names to your predict function. You should be passing numeric data that can be used to generate a prediction. I am referring to this code: `prediction = load_model.predict([['number_of_completed_surveys','hcahps_linear_mean_value ... ...`

Comment: @topsail Do you mean something like this: 'load_model.predict(X[0:1])'. If so, what will be the input here? 'result = US_hospital_prediction(df.iloc[:,:-1])'

Comment: Your prediction function (I am speaking very generally) takes the same input as when you trained it. So, for instance, if it was trained on a dataframe of X values with 10 columns (10 features), then when you call predict you also give the function a list of 10 datapoints for the same 10 features - its more like a single row now though, but just like a single row from the original training data.

Comment: Your model has 18 features, your input for prediction should also have 18 features. Is your model from xgboost or lightgbm? Is it  a binary classifier?

Comment: @ferdy Random Forest classifier. Actually I included all the stages: feature engineering, selection and model training in a pipeline. How do I go about coding the 18 features in the predict() and also in the result below?

Comment: I posted an answer with sample code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplified sample code with 4 features only and a binary target 0/1.

###### Code

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
import joblib
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def make_model(X, y):
    """Create a random forest model from the given feature X and target y.

    Returns:
      model
    """
    clf = RandomForestClassifier(max_depth=2, random_state=0)
    clf.fit(X, y)
    return clf


if __name__ == '__main__':
    mfn = 'random_forest.joblib'  # model filename

    # Sample 5 data with 4 features and binary target in last column.
    Xi = [[-1.6685316675305422, -1.2990134593088984, 0.27464720361244455, -0.6036204360190907, 0],
         [-2.972882695857102, -1.0887829427357882, 0.7088595753671403, 0.42281857467666145, 1],
         [-0.59614125463865, -1.3700700062927567, -3.116856591599126, 0.6444520334110423, 1],
         [-1.0689467425902022, -1.1750573823317514, -1.913742670861507, 0.6635615765913815, 0],
         [-1.3052688750576689, -0.9659256570062029, -0.1540723984248353, 1.193611680749198, 0]]

    df = pd.DataFrame(Xi, columns=['f1', 'f2', 'f3', 'f4', 'target'])
    # print(df)

    X = df[['f1', 'f2', 'f3', 'f4']]
    y = df['target']

    nX = np.array(X)
    ny = np.array(y)

    model = make_model(nX, ny)
    joblib.dump(model, mfn)  # save model

    # f1=0.5, f2=-0.3, f3=2.1, f4=0.6
    test = [0.5, -0.3, 2.1, 0.6]    

    loaded_rf = joblib.load(mfn)
    prediction = loaded_rf.predict([test])

    print(f'test: {test}')
    print(f'prediction: {prediction[0]}')
```

###### Output

```
test: [0.5, -0.3, 2.1, 0.6]
prediction: 1
```

### Streamlit

```
import joblib

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import streamlit as st


def make_model(X, y):
    """Create a random forest model from the given feature X and target y.

    Returns:
      model
    """
    clf = RandomForestClassifier(max_depth=2, random_state=0)
    clf.fit(X, y)
    return clf


if __name__ == '__main__':
    mfn = 'random_forest.joblib'  # model filename

    # Sample 5 data with 4 features and binary target in last column.
    Xi = [[-1.6685316675305422, -1.2990134593088984, 0.27464720361244455, -0.6036204360190907, 0],
         [-2.972882695857102, -1.0887829427357882, 0.7088595753671403, 0.42281857467666145, 1],
         [-0.59614125463865, -1.3700700062927567, -3.116856591599126, 0.6444520334110423, 1],
         [-1.0689467425902022, -1.1750573823317514, -1.913742670861507, 0.6635615765913815, 0],
         [-1.3052688750576689, -0.9659256570062029, -0.1540723984248353, 1.193611680749198, 0]]

    df = pd.DataFrame(Xi, columns=['f1', 'f2', 'f3', 'f4', 'target'])
    print(df)

    X = df[['f1', 'f2', 'f3', 'f4']]
    y = df['target']

    nX = np.array(X)
    ny = np.array(y)

    model = make_model(nX, ny)
    joblib.dump(model, mfn)  # save model

    # f1=0.5, f2=-0.3, f3=2.1, f4=0.6
    # test = [0.5, -0.3, 2.1, 0.6]  

    with st.form(key='form', clear_on_submit=False):
        col = st.columns(2)
        with col[0]:
            f1 = st.number_input(label='feature 1', value=0.5)
            f2 = st.number_input(label='feature 2', value=-0.3)
        with col[1]:
            f3 = st.number_input(label='feature 3', value=2.1)
            f4 = st.number_input(label='feature 4', value=0.6)

        test = [f1, f2, f3, f4]

        pred = st.form_submit_button("Predict")

    if pred:
        loaded_rf = joblib.load(mfn)
        prediction = loaded_rf.predict([test])

        st.write('### Test')
        st.json(test, expanded=False)

        st.write('### Prediction')
        st.write(prediction[0])
```

#### Output

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response, I followed your lead and I'm getting the following error: `StreamlitAPIException: There are multiple identical forms with key='form'.` That's because I have 2449 unique hospital entries in one column and 52 unique states in another column of the form.

Comment: On `There are multiple identical forms with key='form'` you probably have more than 1 form, in that case use a unique keys like key='form1', key='form2' and so on.

Answer (score 0):

As at the time this question was posted, I didn't know HTML and other languages used for front-end. When I learnt the languages, I took a different route in solving the problem. Already, I had used column transformer and pipeline in my notebook so I retrained the model with the eight selected features and pickled it in order to use flask framework to create my web api. Below is the code that solved my problem:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
import pickle
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, url_for, redirect, session, flash

app = Flask(__name__)  

with open('hospital_model.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    model = pickle.load(f)


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])  
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/prediction/', methods=['POST'])
def prediction():
    input_dict = request.form.to_dict()
    print(input_dict)
    input_df = pd.DataFrame(input_dict, index=[1])
    prediction = model.predict(input_df)
    print(prediction)

    return render_template('index.html', prediction=prediction[0])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I then wrote my index.html file along with some CSS